# Prove the following summation identity

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, summation

Let $$\sigma_k (n)= \sum_{j = 1}^{n} j^k$$ and $$\Psi_k (n)= \sum_{j = 1}^{n} \sigma_k (j).$$

Prove the following without use of the respective polynomial equations associated with $\sigma_k$ and $\Psi_k$. $$\sigma_1 (n) * \Psi_1 (n) = n \Psi_2 (n) .$$
$$$$
CONTEXT:
When proving the famous theorem $\sigma_3 (n)= \sigma_1 ^2 (n)$ you may uncover the following identity
$$\sigma_1 (n-1) + \sigma_1 (n) = n^2 .$$
Therefore (with $\sigma_k (0) = 0$ for all $k$)
$$\sigma_2 (n) = \sum_{j=1}^{n} \bigg[\sigma_1 (j-1) + \sigma_1 (j)\bigg] .$$
Expanding the sum gives the result
$$\sigma_2 (n) = \sigma_1 (n) + \sum_{j = 1}^{n-1} 2\sigma_1 (j)$$ which is where our interest in $\Psi_k$ begins.
Using difference tables and linear algebra, it is relatively easy to find polynomial expressions for $\Psi_k$. I have found
$$\Psi_1 (n) = \frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{6}$$
$$\Psi_2 (n)= \frac{1}{12} n^{4} + \frac{1}{3} n^{3} + \frac{5}{12} n^{2} + \frac{1}{6} n .$$
I have found polynomial expressions for up to $\Psi_{13}$, but those are irrelevant in the context of this problem. I noticed that $\sigma_1 (n) * \Psi_1 (n) = n \Psi_2 (n)$ while fooling around with these and that is the motivation for the problem I have posted today. I'm not great with summations, but many users on this site have amazing insight into these kinds of problems, and was looking for some interesting takes. Thanks.

Comment: It would be nice if you gave some motivation for this question – where does it come from, in what mathematical context does it arise, what approaches have you tried, where did you get stuck, and so on.

Comment: Sure, I'll give some context, one sec

Comment: Hope the context helps motivate the problem.